# hex change the dwHeight value inside an .avi video file via commandline?

Tags: windows, video, batch, avi

I wonder if does exist a way to change, via commandline in windows, the height value tag of an .avi file like this temp.avi

https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/c6be6f53-50c7-4f8f-87dc-365d232a4f47

so that the height internal tag change from the originally 1088 to 1080

hex change from 4008 into 3808 in 3 points

from

[image]

and this is the target:

[image]

thanks

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)